# How to upload files ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I'm having some problems with uploading files using Ajax post. 
I have a form with several inputs (checkboxes, texts and files).

```
<form>
<input name="name" type="text">    
<input name="file" type="file" multiple>
<input type="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

I've got a function that retrieves the data from the form:

```
function collectFormData(){
        return {
            "event": $('#daEvent').find('input:checked').next().text(),
            "likes": $('#daLike').find('input:checked').next().text(),
            "figure": $('#daFigure').find('input:checked').next().text(),
            "age": $('#daAgeText').val(),
            "email": $('#daEmail').val(),
            "extraText": $('#daFreeText').find('textarea').val(),
            "files": $('#daUploadPhotos').find('input').get(0).files[0]
        };
    }
```

And it's passed down to:

```
var dataFromPage = collectFormData();
```

And here's my post:

```
$.post('http://localhost:3000', dataFromPage, function(data){
        if (data == "done"){
            alert('works');
        } else {
            alert('damn, something wrong');
        }
    });
```

I get this error -

> Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

I've looked for a solution for a while now, but couldn't find any relevant answers. 
Could you please help me out?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you know the exact line of code that this error complains about?

Comment: Use jQuery form plugin fo ajax submit. You don't need to get form values and send it, just submit this form by ajaxsubmit. Get plugin here : http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

Comment: @PM77-1 nope, it's on minified jquery...

Comment: @OlegYudovich Thanks, looks cool, but it's important for me to understand.

Comment: Does the error occur before attempting the `$.post`? ie: is it caused by `collectFormData`? if yes, go through each of the properties being returned, and find out which one is causing it.